# Grouping overloads in doxygen

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen, overloading

In my library I have a lot of function overloads of the form:

```
/// \brief Does thing.
///
/// \details The thing that is done is very special.
template<typename T>
void do_stuff(const T& t);

/// \brief Does thing repeatedly. 
/// \copydetails do_stuff()
template<typename T>
void do_stuff(const T& t, std::size_t x);
```

This, in general, works and is quite nice but creates the same
documentation section multiple times.  What I want is, to group those
functions together. Have on detail description and each of the
overloads annotated with it's brief description. I'm also not averse
to aliases that could do something like this or input filters.

One way I could imagine this would be:

The documentation result should look like this:

```
template<typename T>
void do_stuff(const T& t);                (1)

template<typename T>
void do_stuff(const T& t, std::size_t x); (2)

The things that is done is very special.

(1) Does thing.

(2) Does thing repeatedly.
```

Of course I can create a new page and write that kind of documentation
by hand, but it would require me to repeat the function declarations
onto the page and then punch links into the actual function
documentation, but that is more a hack than anything else.

Is there a way to achieve this easily? Even hints to hack it into
doxygen would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

Sadly, Doxygen doesn't really have a mechanism to do this. The closest thing you could get are member groups, but those don't do what you need (they only appear in the list of member prototypes).

Hacking it into Doxygen, without modifying Doxygen itself, would generally involve parsing it's XML format, which presents a number of problems. First, its XML format is *terrible* for doing anything useful (believe me; I've tried). Second, there is no syntax for creating a linkage between these functions. The `copydetails` line is like `#include` in C/C++; it leaves no traces after the inclusion. So you can't tell when it was actually used.

Third, you'd be throwing away all of the other formatting that Doxygen provides. You would be writing a full generator for whatever format you're interested in.

Modifying Doxygen itself to support this will involve a number of steps. First, you have to add special grammar that links the commands. This includes modifying the `FuncDef` class to have a reference to another `FuncDef` that it is grouped with. Second, you need to modify the HTML generator to generate them in the same place. That one is going to be a *lot* harder than it sounds. Unless Doxygen's internal source code has gotten a lot better since I last saw it, it will be a significant pain to do.

The HTML generator has some basic assumptions about what links to what, and what you're looking for breaks them. And remember: you're not the first person who has wanted this from Doxygen. And yet, it hasn't been done yet. One of the reasons is that it's non-trivial to implement. Though honestly, I imagine another reason is that Dimitri simply doesn't believe that this is something documentation should ever actually do.

Comment: Sadly, i know all those things, because I have already tried them. My current approach involves adding JavaScript and custom `div` elements to combine items when they are in the same group. I only care about HTML, so this would work for me. Care about getting together to build a new C++ documentation system?

Comment: @pmr: Honestly, I wouldn't want to build a new documentation system. Not from scratch. 99% of it would just be doing what Doxygen does now. The main problem with Doxygen is that it combines the parsing and collation of data with formatting. It doesn't have a good way to extract the documentation data into a raw format that can be transformed as the user sees fit. The XML format just isn't good enough.

Comment: @pmr: I once spent some time writing a new XML output format for Doxygen that actually included all of the relevant information in an easily digestible format. I even submitted an early version (that was mostly functional) as a patch, but there wasn't much interest on the Doxygen mailing list.

Comment: Yes, I was looking into those things. First of replace the parser with libclang, get a separate parser for comments, get a proper intermediate representation. After that, think about back-ends.

My patches got accepted and integrated relatively quickly for now. Maybe its a matter of size.

Answer (score 15):

You can use @name tag to reach the similar functionality.
Take a look at the example, that's easy.

```
    /**
     * @name Appends data to the container.
     *
     * @param tag Name of the data entry
     * @param value Data value
     */
    //@{
    /**
     * @brief Documentation for this overload
     */
    void append(const std::string & tag, bool value);

    /**
     * @brief Documentation for this overload
     */
    void append(const std::string & tag, int8_t value);

    void append(const std::string & tag, int16_t value);
    void append(const std::string & tag, int32_t value);
    //@}
```

It produces the following output:[image]

I hope this will help

Comment: AFAIK, this only works for member groups. I should have mentioned that I need this to work for free functions.

Comment: @pmr No, it also definitely works for functions inside namespace. However I have never tried free functions without namespace, because I don't have such functions.

Comment: A good start. So this is essentially the same solution as using a separate group per overload?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but this is a separate group for all overloads, not "a group per overload". Then you can have separate documentation per each overload in the group.

Comment: I meant "separate group per overloaded name". Which means it amounts to the same as doing `\addtogroup` for all overloads of a name.

Comment: You can see the detailed explanation with examples here: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/grouping.html

Comment: Member groups only really group things in the short description function list. They don't appear in the long-form documentation. So this doesn't really help much.